# Improve number compression algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I have many unique numbers, all positive and the order doesn't matter, `0 < num < 2^32`.
Example: `23 56 24 26`

The biggest, `56`, needs `6 bits` space. So, I need: `4*6 = 24 bits` in total.

**I do the following to save space:**
I sort them first: `23 24 26 56` (because the order doesn't matter)
Now I get the difference of each from the previous: `23 1 2 30`

The biggest, `30`, needs `5 bits` space.
After this I store all the numbers in `4*5 bits = 20 bits` space.

**Question: how to further improve this algorithm?**

**More information:** Since requested, the numbers are mostly on the range of `2.000-4.000`. Numbers less than `300` are pretty rare. Numbers more than `16.000` are pretty rare also. Generally speaking, all the numbers will be close. For example, they may be all in the `1.000-2.000` range or they may all be in the `16.000-20.000` range. The total number of numbers will be something in the range of `500-5.000`.

Comment: The difference between 56 and 26 is 30, so that would be the biggest ;)

Comment: I don't understand the bit calculations... where do you store the format so it can be decoded?

Comment: anyway, this question cannot be properly answered, as it all depends on the distribution and the number of numbers... or you have to explain at least 20 different compression techniques.. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first step is good one to take because sorting reduces the differences to least. Here is a way to improve your algorithm:

1. sort and calculate differences as you have done.
2. Use [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) on it.

Use of Huffman coding is more important then your step; I'll show you why:

consider the following data:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 4294967295
```

where 4294967295 = 2^32-1. Using your algorithm:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4294967288
```

total bits needed is still 32*8

Using Huffman coding, the frequencies are:

```
1 => 7
4294967288 => 1
```

Huffman codes are `1 => 0` and `4294967288 => 1`

Total bits needed = 7*1 + 1 = 8 bits

Huffman coding reduces size by 32*8/8 = 32 times

Comment: @KarolyHorvath didnt want convey anything special there just didnt want to evaluate that because it is easier to show like that it takes 32-bits

Comment: I was confused by the parentheses as well. I'll remove them.

Comment: aaah.. is that the last number in the list?

Comment: You still need to store the mapping `4294967288 => 1` somewhere, so I guess it's a bit more than 8 bits in the end. Anyway, +1

Comment: @tobias_k Good point guess i realized that later but thought its better to leave it uncomplicated

Answer (score 4):

This problem is well known in database community as "Inverted index compression". You can google for some papers.

Following are some of the most common techniques:

- Variable byte coding (VByte)
- Simple9, Simple16
- "Frame Of Reference" family of techniques

  - PForDelta
  - Adaptive Frame Of Reference (AFOR)
- [Rice-Golomb coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_coding) (often used as a part of other techniques)

VByte and Simple9/16 are easiest to implement, fast and have good compression ratio in practice.

Huffman coding is not very good for index compression because it is slow and differences are quite random in practice. (But it may be a good choice in your case.)

Comment: I wouldn't call Huffman coding slow.. unless it's done wrong, of course.

Comment: Huffman coding is heavily bitwise, faster methods concentrate more on byte/word manipulation. And of course it is not fair to compare Huffman and smth like Simple9, they have different use cases.

Comment: If you only know the bit-by-bit way to do Huffman coding, it's not surprising you think it's slow. Outside of the classroom however, no one actually implements Huffman coding that way. There are several table-based decoding algorithms that are used in practice.

Comment: @MaxTaldykin If large numbers are taken then differences cannot be that random morever if small amount of numbers are taken then huffman takes O(logn) bits per number hence in any case huffman gives good results.

Comment: It is slow only when compared to the techniques I listed. Table-base Huffman is not used for index compression due to bad cache locality.

Comment: @VikramBhat, techniques I provided allow to pack small integers in as few bits as possible, they are local and don't use knowledge about distribution of numbers. Also, they are designed to be very fast and cache friendly. If your differences are grouped in some patterns and extra speed is not what you want, Huffman coding (or something similar) will be better choice.

Comment: @maxtaldykin Table based huffman coding is used in image compression and audio compression which are real time applications so i dont think is slow compared to other technique

Comment: @VikramBhat, "it is not fair to compare Huffman and smth like Simple9, they have different use cases"

Comment: @maxtaldykin Only thing that i agree here is that fast implementations are a bit complex to code for huffman.

Answer (score 2):

How many numbers do you have ?  If your set covers the range `[0..(2^32)-1]` densely enough (you do the maths) then a 4GiB bitfield, where the `n`-th bit represents the presence, or absence, of the natural number `n` may be useful.

Comment: if it is really dense, encode the numbers which are *missing*. probably will take less space than 4GiB.

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are not uniformly distributed, a better compression will be achieved by using frequencies of the numbers and affect less bits to most frequent ones. This is the idea behind [huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

Comment: To quote form the question: "I have many _unique_ numbers...". I guess that means "unique" as in "each number has the same frequency, and that is 1"

Comment: @tobias_k you are right, i missed the "unique" point.  Huffman can be applied to differences .